# Get root element of fancytree

Tags: jquery, fancytree

I have something like this :

```
-Root 1
--Folder 1
--Folder 2
---Element 1
-Root 2
--Folder 3
---Folder 4
----Element 2
```

I have a `'select'` listener for elements and I need to choose the name or key of `Root 1` or `Root 2` when I choose `Element 1` or `Element 2` accordingly.

is `$("#tree").fancytree("getRootNode")` the right way and what exactly should I use to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the node and its parent in the event handler using [`node.getParentList()`](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/FancytreeNode.html#getParentList):

```
select: function(event, data) {
    var parentNode = data.node.getParent(),
        topNode = data.node.getParentList()[0];
}
```